# How do I find the shortest Regex match when using an OR Group?

Tags: regex

My intention is to match complete sentences ( or equivalent ) with the Regex below.  In the first group, I'd like my OR pattern to match a period first ( indicating the end of the previous sentence ), then, if there are no periods within the 128 character range, match a quote, then match a new line, then the end of an HTML tag, then a word boundary, etc.

How can I setup this regex to give priority to specific matches like this?

```
<?php
  $regex = '/((\.|"|\n|>|\b).{0,128}\b(manufacturer|manufacture|manufactures)\b.{0,128}(\.|<\/|"|\n|\b))/i';
  $string = '<title>Carter Bearings - Bearings are our Business. Manufacturer of Bearings and Rollers</title>';
  preg_match_all( $regex, $string, $matches );
  var_dump( $matches );
?>
```

This matches the following string from `$string`:

```
title>Carter Bearings - Bearings are our Business. Manufacturer of Bearings and Rollers</title
```

I would like to match the shortest version that roughly represents a separate but complete part of the string:

```
. Manufacturer of Bearings and Rollers</
```

Comment: `(manufacture[rs]*)` == `(manufacturer|manufacture|manufactures)`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question but if you want to shorten your regex you could use: `(([\."\n>\b]).{0,128}\b(manufacture[rs]?)\b.{0,128}([\."\n\b]|<\/))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't because a regex engine works from left to right and will give you all non-overlapping matches *(with `preg_match_all`)* from the left to the right for each possible positions in the string. The only way is to find the shortest result is to use `strlen` or better `mb_strlen` after.

As an aside, as Dalorzo notices it, your pattern can be shorten:

```
$regex = '/(?:[."\n>]|\b).{0,128}\bmanufacture[rs]?\b.{0,128}(?:[."\n<]|\b)/i';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you need, but here's my best guess at *literally* translating what you said:

```
(\.|
  (?!.{0,128}?\.) # make sure there is no period in the next 128 characters
  (?:"|\n|>|\b)
)
\b(manufacturer|manufacture|manufactures)\b
.{0,128}?         # consume at most 128 characters, but as few as possible
(?=\.|<\/|"|\n)   # ... until you encounter one of these
```

Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/iV7xL5/1

This matches `Manufacturer of Bearings and Rollers` in your example.